# How to make a method in a class, manipulate variables in another class?

Tags: java, class, methods

Working on a simple tic-tac-toe game in Java.

I have a class named `GameHelpers`. This class should contain useful methods for the game. The game happenes in another class.

A method in `GameHelpers` is `ResetGame()`. This method is supposed to set the text on all the 9 buttons (the tic-tac-toe board) to blank, set them enabled again, and set a variable to 1.

This is it's code:

```
public class GameHelpers {

    public void resetGame(){
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                buttons[i][j].setEnabled(true);
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`buttons[]` is an array of JButtons inside the main class of the game, `TicTacToe`.

This method was previously inside the main class of the game, `TicTacToe`. But now that it's in a different class, it can't reach the buttons in the `TicTacToe` class and manipulate them.

I created get and set methods in `TicTacToe`, but how do I activate them from `GameHelpers`?

How can I make the method in `GameHelpers` work?

Comment: If you're only going to be developing for Windows, may I suggest using `C#`.  It's quite similar to java, syntactically; plus, it's trivial to get an executable from your program.  Obviously this is my opinion, but I think that `C#` offers many things that [I would love to see in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610199/the-art-of-programming-java-vs-c-sharp).  `C#` is what I wish `Java` would be...

Comment: Why did you edit your question into a totally new question when you already had an accepted answer? Now these answers make no sense.

Comment: The answers do not fit your question anymore after editing the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may refer [Java to EXE - Why, When, When Not and How](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/java2exe/)

> **Drawbacks**
>
> **Disk footprint.** Java bytecode has been designed for compactness, so it has a much higher level than a typical CPU instruction set.
>   Expect that an executable produced by an AOT compiler will be 2-4
>   times larger than the original jar file.
>
> **Dynamic applications**. Classes that the application loads dynamically at runtime may be unavailable to the application
>   developer. These can be third-party plug-ins, dynamic proxies and
>   other classes generated at runtime and so on. So the runtime system
>   has to include a Java bytecode interpreter and/or a JIT compiler.
>
> Moreover, in the general case only classes that are loaded by either
>   system or application classloader may be precompiled to native code.
>   So applications that use custom classloaders extensively may only be
>   partially precompiled.
>
> **Hardware-specific optimizations.** A JIT compiler has a potential advantage over AOT compilers in that it can select code generation
>   patterns according to the actual hardware on which the application is
>   executing. For instance, it may use Intel MMX/SSE/SSE2 extensions to
>   speedup floating point calculations. An AOT compiler must either
>   produce code for the lowest common denominator or apply versioning to
>   the most CPU-intensive methods, which results in further code size
>   increase.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from personal experience, if there's a bug that's only present in the EXE version, you might end up spending a lot of time trying to track it down and decide it's just easier to give users the other version instead.

It sounds to me like you're really trying to make things easier on your users overall. I don't know what your budget is, but perhaps something like [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/buy/install4j/select) would be a better solution.